# recyclerview showing empty white screen

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

I am new kotlin and recently started working with retrofit and I have followed this tutorial http://velmm.com/kotlin-retrofit-android-example-with-recyclerview/

but when I run code it is showing empty white screen below
[empty screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt0m1.png)

below my MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
    recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(this)
    recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter


    val apiInterface = ApiInterface.create().getMovies()

    //apiInterface.enqueue( Callback<List<Movie>>())
    apiInterface.enqueue( object : Callback<List<Movie>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Movie>>?, response: Response<List<Movie>>?) {

            if(response?.body() != null)
                recyclerAdapter.setMovieListItems(response.body()!!)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Movie>>?, t: Throwable?) {

        }
    })
}
```

}

below Adapter class
class RecyclerAdapter(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter() {

```
var movieList : List<Movie> = listOf()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_adapter,parent,false)
    return MyViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return movieList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.tvMovieName.text = movieList.get(position).title
    Glide.with(context).load(movieList.get(position).image)
        .apply(RequestOptions().centerCrop())
        .into(holder.image)
}

fun setMovieListItems(movieList: List<Movie>){
    this.movieList = movieList;
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {

    val tvMovieName: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.title)
    val image: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.image)

}
```

}

below ApiInterface.kt
interface ApiInterface {

```
@GET("volley_array.json")
fun getMovies() : Call<List<Movie>>

companion object {

    var BASE_URL = "http://35.200.174.74/apis/"

    fun create() : ApiInterface {

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    }
}
```

}

below Movie.kt

```
 data class Movie(var title: String, var image: String)
```

below  recyclerview_adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="150dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

below activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you checked the layout inspector? You are not providing the complete item xml file content so there could be an issue there.

Comment: @NoSoyBeto I have added missing xml item please check it

Comment: No `else` case for HTTP errors, empty `onFailure` for connection errors. You won't know if anything goes wrong.

Comment: @Miha_x64 what is your suggestion in this case

Comment: Add this `t?.printStackTrace()` on the failure callback, and then check for an error in the logcat console.

Comment: Well there's a good chance that you won't know if there's a failure or not, because you are not doing anything when the request fails.

Comment: what is your suggestiom

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what is your suggestion then

Comment: Add a log statement in `onFailure`

Comment: added already it did not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue at the  `recyclerview_adapter.xml` file. You should not use `match_parent` inside constraint layout but 0dp, and when doing it you must take into account you need to constraint start and end if  you want full width, or top and bottom if you want to do it vertically. Here how the file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="150dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the activity should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                         tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons, the other one is that you are ignoring the failure callback on the MainActivity. An error as InternetPermission may be causing an issue. Print the stack trace and add it here please.

Comment: And the condition `if(response?.body() != null)` is ever happening? Add an else clause and check if it is happening.

Comment: else clause what I have to write

Comment: At least a Log.i("ELSE CLAUSE", "The response is empty"). If that is happening, there is something wrong on the api call.

Comment: it is still the same white screen

Comment: Yes, but what you have to check is the logcat console. If there is no data because something is wrong with the api call, then of course nothing will ever be shown.

Comment: Is `setMovieListItems` ever being called?

Comment: Also verify this, the text is white and maybe there is an error on the images and then, you could be seeing a white screen, but it is because the images are not loading. Just to verify, change the text color to black and try again.

Comment: it is still the same

Comment: You better use the debugger, the tool will lead you step by step and let you check the vars. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug